# Is a Time series' Model always an Additive or Multiplicative one?

Tags: time-series, decomposition

A Time Series consits of four components trend, seasonality, cyclical and an irregular component. Now a time series can be decomposed in an 
 Additive or Multiplicative Model. Are there other possiblities and does one in real world applications always try to decompose a series in these four components?
Some enlightening is welcome!

Comment: Your introductory statement is only one of many ways to think about time series: it is by no means universally true (unless you use "irregular component" as a catch-all, but then the statement is devoid of meaning).

Comment: @whuber is it only possible to decompose a time series in an additive or multiplicative model, if we think of a time series in this particular manner and if we think of such a model is it a good idea to decompose it into an Additive or Multiplicative Model or is it actually not necessary?

Comment: a time series model can have one or more trends , one or more level shifts , changes in seasonal factors , anomalies , changes in error variance , autoregressive structure , deterministic structure induced by anthropomorphic effects , et al . Only your data knows for sure. If you post one of your example time series , perhaps I and others can try and help.